# Python : Find tuples from a list of tuples having duplicate data in the 0th element(of the tuple)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I am having a list of tuples containing **filename** and **filepath**.
I want to find duplicates **filename**(but **filepath** may be different) i.e. tuples whose filename is same but **filepath** may be different.

Example of a list of tuples:

```
file_info = [('foo1.txt','/home/fold1'), ('foo2.txt','/home/fold2'), ('foo1.txt','/home/fold3')]
```

I want to find the duplicate filename i.e. file_info[2](in the above case) print it and delete it.
I possibly could iteratively check like:

```
count = 0
for (filename,filepath) in file_info:
    count = count + 1
    for (filename1,filepath1) in file_info[count:]:
        if filename == filename1:
            print filename1,filepath1
            file_info.remove((filename1,filepath1))
```

But is there a more efficient/shorter/more correct/pythonic way of accomplishing the same task.
Thank You.

Comment: Your code alters the list as you loop over it, so you will end up skipping items.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a set lets you avoid creating a double loop; add items you haven't seen yet to a *new* list to avoid altering the list you are looping over (which will lead to skipped items):

```
seen = set()
keep = []
for filename, filepath in file_info:
    if filename in seen:
        print filename, filepath
    else:
        seen.add(filename)
        keep.append((filename, filepath))
file_info = keep
```

If order doesn't matter and you don't *have* to print the items you removed, then another approach is to use a dictionary:

```
file_info = dict(reversed(file_info)).items()
```

Reversing the input list assures that the *first* entry is kept rather than the last.

If you needed all the full paths for files with duplicates, I'd build a dictionary with lists as values, then remove anything that has only one element:

```
filename_to_paths = {}
for filename, filepath in file_info:
    filename_to_paths.setdefault(filename, []).append(filepath)
duplicates = {filename: paths for filename, paths in filename_to_paths.iteritems() if len(paths) > 1}
```

The `duplicates` dictionary now only contains filenames where you have more than 1 path in the `file_info` list.

Comment: nice variable name :P of coarse this is an excellent answer :P

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question that I would be needing both of the filepaths containing the duplicate filename.

Comment: @wolframalpha: option added. Basically, when needing unique info, dictionaries and sets can help you filter or group the info.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a mapping with [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and use it to see which paths hold the same file (the file is the key). A mapping's keys are already a set, and it will let you keeps the files for printing and deleting (they will be the mapping's values):

```
from collections import defaultdict

file_info = [
    ('foo1.txt','/home/fold1'),
    ('foo2.txt','/home/fold2'),
    ('foo1.txt','/home/fold3')]

# create a mapping that defaults to an empty list
path_by_file_name = defaultdict(list)

# populate the mapping
for name, path in file_info:
    path_by_file_name[name].append(path)

# find duplicates (lists with more than one item)
duplicates = filter(lambda kv: len(kv[1]) > 1, path_by_file_name.items())

print duplicates # [('foo1.txt', ['/home/fold1', '/home/fold3'])]
```

This is basically as fast as the set solution, but keeps a bigger state (all the files mapped to a file name - which can become handy later). If you have millions of files that can become a problem, but it probably won't.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_uniqe(unique_index,initial_data):
    seen = set()
    for item in initial_data:
        if item[unique_index] not in seen:
           seen.add(item[unique_index])
           yield item

print list(get_unique(0,my_list_of_file_info))
```